# Compare two arrays based on the first N elements of the array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I am trying to turn compare two arrays based on the first three elements of each array. I will then use `array_udiff` to find elements in the first original array that arent in the second original array. Here is my code and current outputs

```
function udiffanswers($a,$b){
    $slicea = array_slice($a,0,3);  
    $sliceb = array_slice($b,0,3);  
    print_r($slicea);
    print_r($sliceb);
    if($slicea == $sliceb)
    {
        return 0;
    }else{
        return -1;
    }
}

$diffinanswers = array_udiff($row ,$answers, 'udiffanswers');

echo "diff results \n"; 
print_r($diffinanswers);
```

THIS IS MY INPUT

```
 answers sqlite results 
 Array
  (
  [0] => Array
    (
        [aid] => 432267
        [qid] => 0
        [sid] => 1
        [freetext] => 
        [a] => Dog
        [b] => null 1
        [c] => null 2
        [d] => null 3
        [e] => null 4
        [f] => null 5
        [g] => null 6
        [h] => null 7
        [i] => null 8
        [j] => null 9
        [type] => Multiple Choice
        [location] => 37.334709,-122.034111
    )
 [1] => Array
    (
        [aid] => 1
        [qid] => 0
        [sid] => 1
        [freetext] => 
        [a] => Dog
        [b] => null 1
        [c] => null 2
        [d] => null 3
        [e] => null 4
        [f] => null 5
        [g] => null 6
        [h] => null 7
        [i] => null 8
        [j] => null 9
        [type] => Multiple Choice
        [location] => 37.334709,-122.034111
    )
   )
```

answers mysqli results

```
 Array
 (
 [0] => Array
    (
        [aid] => 42
        [qid] => 0
        [sid] => 1
        [freetext] => 
        [a] => dog
        [b] => 
        [c] => 
        [d] => 
        [e] => 
        [f] => 
        [g] => 
        [h] => 
        [i] => 
        [j] => 
        [type] => 
        [location] => 
    )

   [1] => Array
    (
        [aid] => 432267
        [qid] => 0
        [sid] => 1
        [freetext] => 
        [a] => Dog
        [b] => null 1
        [c] => null 2
        [d] => null 3
        [e] => null 4
        [f] => null 5
        [g] => null 6
        [h] => null 7
        [i] => null 8
        [j] => null 9
        [type] => Multiple Choice
        [location] => 37.334709,-122.034111
    )

   [2] => Array
    (
        [aid] => 432267
        [qid] => 0
        [sid] => 2
        [freetext] => 
        [a] => dog
        [b] => 
        [c] => 
        [d] => 
        [e] => 
        [f] => 
        [g] => 
        [h] => 
        [i] => 
        [j] => 
        [type] => 
        [location] => 
    )

   [3] => Array
    (
        [aid] => 432267
        [qid] => 2
        [sid] => 1
        [freetext] => 
        [a] => dog
        [b] => 
        [c] => 
        [d] => 
        [e] => 
        [f] => 
        [g] => 
        [h] => 
        [i] => 
        [j] => 
        [type] => 
        [location] => 
    )

 )
```

THIS IS THE OUTPUT(but should only contain array[1])

```
  [0] => Array
    (
        [aid] => 432267
        [qid] => 0
        [sid] => 1
        [freetext] => 
        [a] => Dog
        [b] => null 1
        [c] => null 2
        [d] => null 3
        [e] => null 4
        [f] => null 5
        [g] => null 6
        [h] => null 7
        [i] => null 8
        [j] => null 9
        [type] => Multiple Choice
        [location] => 37.334709,-122.034111
    )

 [1] => Array
    (
        [aid] => 1
        [qid] => 0
        [sid] => 1
        [freetext] => 
        [a] => Dog
        [b] => null 1
        [c] => null 2
        [d] => null 3
        [e] => null 4
        [f] => null 5
        [g] => null 6
        [h] => null 7
        [i] => null 8
        [j] => null 9
        [type] => Multiple Choice
        [location] => 37.334709,-122.034111
    )
   )
```

but it is. Im pretty sure the udiff function is not correct but cant figure it out. I only want the unique ones in the sqlite array to be output

Comment: Could you edit your question to explicitly state your input, output, and expected output?

Comment: Have you tried `array_diff` instead if `array_udiff`?

Comment: would array_diff work when  i only care about the first 3 elements? the next elements are allowed to be different/same

Comment: You give an array of 2 arrays to your `array_udiff`, but you're confused that you also get 2 arrays back. If that is in fact the problem, you should probably confront the [manual about array_udiff](http://php.net/array_udiff) again.